# Question regarding preferences in Gale and Shapley (1962)

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, preferences, search-and-matching, matching

Is it correct to say that preferences in the classic Gale and Shapley College Admissions problem are quasi-linear?

Or is this something thats introduced later in the literature, vis a vis Shapley and Shubik (1971), Kelso and Crawford (1982), etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gale and Shapley barely make any assumptions about preferences. They don't need a functional form, simply an ordinal ranking of the options. Moreover, there are no transfers in this setting, only the discrete matching options.

Even Kelso and Crawford do not use quasi-linear utility. They assume some utility function that is increasing and continuous in salary, but not necessarily linearly increasing.

In Shapley and Shubik (1971) monetary transfers enter linearly.
However, I wouldn't call this quasi-linear utility, because in quasi-linear utility most people have the following functional form over a good $x$ and money $m$ in mind: $u(x,m) = v(x) - m$, where $v$ is a continuous function.
In their model, the $v(x)$ is simply the money value of house $x$, where the houses are district options.

Comment: Do Gale and Shapley establish the existence of a core?

Comment: They may not mention it as "the core." However, they prove the existence of stable allocations, which is the same as "the core" in their setting.

Comment: Does Shapley and Shubik (1971) use quasi-linear preferences?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: Sure, consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem so that this question does not remain formally "unanswered".